# How to create correct struct for json

Tags: json, go

how to parse json correctly I have the following json file

```
{
    "hello": {
        "title": "Golang",
        "story": [
            "Go lang story",
            "Channel story"
        ],
        "options": [
            {
                "text": "That story",
                "arc": "west"
            },
            {
                "text": "Gee",
                "arc": "east"
            }
        ]
    },
    "world": {
        "title": "Visiting",
        "story": [
            "Boo",
            "Doo",
            "Moo",
            "Qoo"
        ],
        "options": [
            {
                "text": "weird",
                "arc": "west"
            },
            {
                "text": "funny",
                "arc": "north"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've created these structs for the inner part

```
type chapter struct{
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Story []string `json:"story"`
    Option []option `json:"options"`
}

type option struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
    Arc string `json:"arc"`
}
```

but I don't know how to parse wrappers like "hello" and "world"

Comment: refer golang's [blog](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go), if you find it hard refer [this](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/10/18/parsing-json-in-golang/).

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: In any JSON, keys should be always constant. In your case, "hello" and "world" are keys for corresponding values, but are dynamic hence you have this problem of parsing the JSON. If you can convert it like "{"key" :  "hello", "value": { "title" : .... } }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do structuring the root map.

```
{
    "hello":{},
    "world":{}
}
```

Here the `hello` and `world` is also inside a map. So you need to structure them too.

```
 var root map[string]chapter
 json.Unmarshal(JSONDATA,&root)
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/VZ9Bn215dDW